# why did this transfer transaction fail on eth?

Tags: gas-estimate, out-of-gas

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8ad822a326243e69c4d5bcd3fe07466a82c2c00edbc53cbc0a211c6efbdd7dd2

checked ethgasstation and doubled the gas but it still failed, any ideas why it would?

Comment: The reason is because you run out of gas. High chance the contract function is too expensive to execute that's why it run out of gas. But without the code for the contract we can't know for sure

Answer (score 0):

From the [transaction trace](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x8ad822a326243e69c4d5bcd3fe07466a82c2c00edbc53cbc0a211c6efbdd7dd2) and the low gas used.

It seems it was reverted because you are calling a function that is not payable and sending non zero ether amount.

```
[10]    128   PUSH1      25  3   1
[11]    130   CALLVALUE  22  2   1
[12]    131   GT         20  3   1
[13]    132   ISZERO     17  3   1
[14]    133   PUSH2      14  3   1
[15]    136   JUMPI      11  10  1
[16]    137   PUSH32     1   3   1
```